# Why mongo updates first element in db despite the condition

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

tell me pls why this code updates firs element in db despite the condition. And i couldn't see any logs. Im using `NestJs+Typeorm+Mongo`

```
 await this.workOrderModel
            .updateOne({ createRequestId: 'someMockedVaue' }, { $set: { createFlowTrackingId: 'otherValue' } })
            .then((updatedWorkOrder) => {
              this.logger.verbose('Updated WorkOrder: %o', updatedWorkOrder);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              this.logger.error('Error on update WorkOrder: %o', err);
            });
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code. We need more information. How do the documents look?

Answer (score 0):

I understood what the problem is, if you specify the wrong field in the filter, it takes the first user in the db and changes the data